# What is wrong with this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

```
DELETE
  LIB, REL
FROM
  test_library_song LIB
INNER JOIN
  test_relation REL
ON
  LIB.book_id = REL.book_id
WHERE
  REL.user_id = '1'
AND
  REL.book_id = '400'
LIMIT 1
```

It throws an error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1' at line 13
```

If I remove the LIMIT 1, it works, but I want it on for security measures.

Comment: What security measures do you refer to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I see it, the `LIMIT` is only valid for single table deletions

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

> For the multiple-table syntax, DELETE deletes from each tbl_name the rows that satisfy the conditions. In this case, ORDER BY and LIMIT cannot be used.

Comment: Thanks. Guess I could have figured that one out myself.

Answer (score 1):

LIMIT cannot be used on a multi-table delete. See the [DELETE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) syntax documentation.